# Docker container not showing site based on newly copied site configuration

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

This is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:devel

MAINTAINER ciasto

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/\*

RUN mkdir /var/run/apache2

COPY mysite.conf  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

ENV APACHE\_RUN\_USER www-data

ENV APACHE\_RUN\_GROUP www-data

ENV APACHE\_LOG\_DIR /var/log/apache2

ENV APACHE\_RUN\_DIR /var/run/apache2

EXPOSE 80

CMD \["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D", "FOREGROUND"\]
```

I am trying to load my site instead of default `000-default.conf` but even though the `mysite.conf` overwrites `000-default.conf` I still keep getting the default homepage of Apache instead.

It doesn't have any affect of a2dissite and then running a2ensite:

```
# docker build -t myapache .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/13 : FROM ubuntu:devel
 ---> 3dd27c0da934
Step 2/13 : MAINTAINER ciasto
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ca48c7010bf5
Step 3/13 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3893438f7d96
Step 4/13 : RUN mkdir /var/run/apache2
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6cc65fe8d352
Step 5/13 : COPY mysite.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 469c402f7c57
Step 6/13 : RUN a2dissite 000-default
 ---> Running in 2de611818fc0
Site 000-default disabled.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
Removing intermediate container 2de611818fc0
 ---> 64d8deed8833
Step 7/13 : RUN a2ensite 000-default
 ---> Running in cc8a0374ab0d
Enabling site 000-default.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
Removing intermediate container cc8a0374ab0d
 ---> 3af0de88b74b
Step 8/13 : ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
 ---> Running in fa2146657f5f
Removing intermediate container fa2146657f5f
 ---> dac302f42282
Step 9/13 : ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
 ---> Running in 7a3035b5866d
Removing intermediate container 7a3035b5866d
 ---> fdfc7a1d86e4
Step 10/13 : ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
 ---> Running in 93cc22c81f55
Removing intermediate container 93cc22c81f55
 ---> d8e073243eed
Step 11/13 : ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
 ---> Running in ca2b2829d60c
Removing intermediate container ca2b2829d60c
 ---> c7f535e2c031
Step 12/13 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in 613564334e15
Removing intermediate container 613564334e15
 ---> adae0f0e2aed
Step 13/13 : CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
 ---> Running in 97c845feed9f
Removing intermediate container 97c845feed9f
 ---> 67f7823b995b
Successfully built 67f7823b995b
Successfully tagged myapache:latest
```

then I still get default page of Apache and checked by entering running container:

```
# apachectl -S
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861021/apache-configuration-file-000-default-conf-not-working). To be add after the COPY:

```
RUN a2dissite 000-default
RUN a2ensite 000-default
```

Comment: that doesnt help. I have updated opening post with reasons.